# Tabular model with blank excel

Tags: excel, ssas-tabular

I have a problem with testing my tabular model which I have developed with VS 2022.
I have created a tabular model from an Azure Database and Integrated workspace. Everything is fine in VS. When I analyse the model without perspective the excel opens normally with pivot table menu and option activated. I can give any parameter I want to the pvot table.

The problem is when I try test a perspective. The excel opens with everything disabled and the pvot table options and menu are not appearing. The excel is grey everywhere.

The problem appears only when I select a perspective choice in menu that opens the excel file. If I leave "default" in the perspective drop down menu it works fine.

Does anyone know what is the problem?